# Access scope from another directive

Tags: angularjs

HTML code:

```
<my-button> <my-button> <!-- First directive, contains a button -->

    <modal-data> <!-- Modal from bootstrap. It only show when my-button is clicked -->
       <!--This is a part of the template, rendered with the directive
      <div id="my-modal">
         {{ comments }} !!!!THIS IS NOT RENDERED!!!
      </div>
                -->
   </modal-data>
```

My first directive

```
.directive('myButton', function(){
        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            templateUrl : 'button.html',
            controller : ['$scope', 'apiService', function($scope, apiService){

                this.getComments  = function(){
                    apiService.getComments()
                        .success(function(data){
                            $scope.comments = data;
                        });
                }

            }],
            link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
                element.on('click', function(){
                    ctrl.getComments();
                    $('#my-modal').modal();
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

Modal directive: it only contains a template

```
.directive('modalComments', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl : 'modal.html'
    };
});
```

When `my-button` is clicked, the click listener in the link function is called.
This execute a function in the controller which is a service that takes data from an API.
the output needs to be linked to the modal that will popup.

Problem is I can only access this scope within the `my-button` directive.

Can someone tell me a way to solve this?

**EDIT**

Snippet:

```js
(function(){
      
  angular.module('app', [])

  .controller('controller', function($scope){
    $scope.data = "Hello";

  })

  .directive('myButton', function(){
    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      template : 'Click me',
      controller : ['$scope', function($scope){
        this.getData = function(){
          $scope.data = "HEllo world";
        };
      }],
      link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){

        element.on('click', function(){
          ctrl.getData();

        });

      }

    };
  });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
      

  <my-button> {{ data }}</my-button>
  {{data}}

</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: I added it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afther reading *Up and Running*, if this structure want to be used, a service needs to be created.

We don't need reusability, but we do need aplication level state. Which is one of the purposes of Services.

Up and Running says:

> You don't want to create a parent level controller, wich is never
>   ideal for a large scale, maintanable application

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your solution is bad designed. Instead of using normal button you're creating myButton. Why don't you use:

```
<button ng-click="yourController.getComments()"></button>
```

It's impossible to reuse your myButton because it has a lot of business logic. Your directive is sth like commentsBox not a button

Comment: You are using AngularJS in bad way.  There is a lot of good examples of ToDo lists on the internet. Look at this http://codepen.io/Russbrown/pen/IgBuh

Comment: I was doing it that way 1 month ago, but when the app is growing it is not maintenable + people need to understand easely the code

Comment: Do you know about those kind of stuff? http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html

Comment: Yep, I'm familiar with this and I like the idea. 
You are takling about clean code.. Do you really want to create directive for everything? You've got the problem with accessing comments collection because you've got a problem with scoping. Your're storing comments in button scope and this is crazy - in my opinion. So know you have to add another shared service to have the access in your another directive. I like KISS rule and well design architecture.

Comment: Allright then. But I'm not storing those comments in a button directive. They are in a modal. Did you bought a book a something to learn it? I bought up and running, I think there's no better way to learn this than a book...